# Showing that for any $\epsilon > 0$, the function $\frac{1}{z + i} + \sin(z)$ has an infinite number of zeros.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:**

> Prove that, for any given $\epsilon > 0$, the function $$ z \mapsto \frac{1}{z + i} + \sin(z) $$ has an infinite number of zeros in the strip $|\text{Im}(z) | < \epsilon$.

**Attempt:** I was trying to apply Rouche's theorem to this problem. But to apply this theorem, I need to specify an open set containing a circle $C$ and its interior. Then I can compare the number of zeros of holomorphic functions $f$ and $f + g$ inside this circle. However, I'm confused because here the region is an infinite strip.

In this case, I would let $f(z) = \sin(z)$ and $g(z) = \frac{1}{z+i}$. I was looking to bound $g(z)$ by $f(z)$ somehow and then argue that since $\sin(z)$ has an infinite number of zeros, so does the stated function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at $f$ and $g$ on circles of radius $\epsilon$ around the zeroes of $f$. You should aim to apply Rouché's theorem on all but finitely many of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\frac{1}{z+i} +\sin(z)=0$ has infinite solutions over $\mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186925/prove-that-frac1zi-sinz-0-has-infinite-solutions-over-mathbbc)

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759800/counting-zeros-with-rouches-theorem